# How to add to a column the difference between another column and the one to place data on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I have a file with 2 sheets (`Tracker` and `RawData`) to store products to send to my clients.

`Tracker` is used by my distributor to assign each order number to a courier, while I place all the order numbers on `RawData`.

I want to run a script that take all the order numbers on `RawData` and subtract rows duplicated that `Tracker` has, then add all the new order numbers to the `Tracker` after the last row.

```
function removeDups() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RawData");
  var backUpSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker");
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var actQueue = backUpSheet.getRange("M2:M").getValues();
  var addQueue = activeSheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var resultArray = [];

  for (var n = 0; n < addQueue.length; n++){
    if (addQueue[n] == actQueue[n]) {
      resultArray.push(n);
      Logger.log(resultArray)
    }
  }
  for (var m = 0; m <= resultArray.lenght; m++){
    activeSheet.deleteRow(resultArray[m]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is your as-is code, note that `.lenght` is almost certainly an undefined property of the `resultArray` variable (you probably meant .`length`). Also note that you will want to delete rows from `activeSheet` in reverse order, because as soon as you delete the first one, you need to compensate for the row removal in your stored row indices. (There is also the 0-base vs 1-base numbering difference between JavaScript `Array`s and the Spreadsheet model.)

Comment: @hkviktor Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?